# Replace spaces in KSH with SED

Tags: unix, sed, ksh

I am building a find command programatically:

```
find  "${SRC_DIR}" "${FILE_NAMES}" -type f -mtime +14 -level 0
```

Where FILE_NAMES is the file patterns that I need to match, which is a simple whitespace delimited list of patterns (*.txt, *.html, etc).

To format this list correctly for the find command, it can't just be a list though, it has to look like:

```
-name *.txt -o -name *.html
```

My solution was to use:

```
FILE_NAMES=$(echo ${FILES} | sed -e 's/\s+/-o -name /g')
```

But it's not working, specifically it doesn't seem to understand that I want to replace whitespace. Does anyone have a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all seds support perl-like place holders for space, digits, etc. I don't have a way to test your exact case, but the following should be a good guide.

Also, note that `find -predicate  -predicate ....` are ANDed by default. to make the `-o` work, you have to surrond the whole thing in `( (parens) )` AND so the shell won't see the paren as a request to launch a subshell, you have to escape the parens, i.e `\( .... -o .... \)`. So that leads us to

```
 set -vx; SRC_DIR="." ; FILE_NAMES="a b c"
 find  "${SRC_DIR}" \( $(echo "$FILE_NAMES"| sed 's/ / -o -name /g;s/^/-name /') \) -type f -mtime +14 -level 0
```

OUTPUT

```
+ echo 'a b c'
+ sed 's/ / -o -name /g;s/^/-name /'
+ find . '\( -name a -o -name b  -o -name c \)' -type f -mtime +14 -level 0
find: invalid predicate `-level'
```

which just indicates that my find doesn't support -level either.

**edit** removed extra `"` chars surounding the `\(....\)`.

**also**

If you're using a ksh93, it maybe possible to use variable modifiers, like

```
${FILE_NAME// / -o -name}
```

But you'll need to either just concatenate the opening `-name` or do a 2nd substitution on the saved value of FILE_NAME.

You can see if you have ksh93 by issuing the following cmd

```
echo ${.sh.version}
```

If you get a value, then you have ksh93.

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

ksh:

```
FILES='*.txt *.html'
FILE_NAMES=$(
  # $() runs this script in a subshell
  conjunction=""
  set -f   # turn off file pattern expansion
  for patt in $FILES; do
    printf "%s -name '%s' " "$conjunction" "$patt"
    conjunction="-o"
  done
)
find  "${SRC_DIR}" ${FILE_NAMES} -type f -mtime +14 -level 0
```

Note that `$FILE_NAMES` is *not quoted* -- you want the shell to split the variable into separate words.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to take a different approach:

```
find ${SRC_DIR} -type f -mtime +14 | egrep '\.(txt|html)$'
```

I left out the `-level 0` bit because I have no idea what it's for - it doesn't exist in the version I have at hand. You could always put it back in...

Comment: Your solution hardcodes txt and html, which is not what I want.

Comment: True, but there's nothing preventing using `egrep "${VAR1}|${VAR2}"` or something similar. It was intended more as an example of using an alternate approach that avoided all the work of properly constructing a complex `find` command line...

Comment: Note you can also put a list of patterns to match in a file and use `egrep -f <filename>` rather than trying to construct a command line regular expression that is a huge list of alternates.